# Dictionary values change after first run in QGIS 3.24.1, how to solve it?

Tags: python, qgis

I wrote a script that imports layers, adds filter to them etc.
The script uses a dictionary to get the specific values for each layer.
The dictionary is made by another script and imported to the script I'm running in QGIS. The imported dictionary has 4 values for each key.

The script I'm running in QGIS adds another value to the dictionary, using a while loop as shown in the example.

```
dict_name[key] = dict_name[key], added_value
```

When I run the script for the first time it works great without any errors. When I run it for the second time, it seems to have saved the dict from the previous run. As I try to access one of the original keys, using `dict_name[1]`, it actually returns the `added_value` I've added to the dict in the previous run.

That causes me to either change the code to `dict_name[0][1]` or reopen QGIS so I can run it again.
When I tested it in PyCharm, I didn't face the same issue after multiple runs.

I'm running `QgsProject.instance().clear()` in QGIS between the two runs, it delets all the layers but the dict is still accessable via the console. I believe it is being cached somewhere, I just can't figure where and how to stop it from caching it. I've tried `del dict_name` after running `QgsProject.instance().clear()`, the console returned `NameError: name 'dict_name' is not defined` when trying to print it but I kept having the same error.

How do I solve this issue in QGIS 3.24.1, Python 3.9.5

Edit:
Adding bits of the script:

This script is in charge of making the dictionary, it gets it data from a csv.

```
    category_names = rows[3][1:]
    category = rows[4][1:]
    dts_rng = rows[5][1:]
    rds = rows[6][1:]
    dict_name = {}
    i = 0
    for w in category_names:
        temppath = f"{path}//{category_names[i]}.gpkg|layername={category_names[i]}"
        dict_name[w] = w
        dict_name[w] = category[i], dts_rng[i], rds[i], temppath
        i += 1
```

In the main script I'm importing `dict_name` and adding info to it from a list `new_dict[cat] = dict_name[cat], full_fltr_lst`.

I've placed the script that in charge of making the dictionary in QGIS 3.24.1\apps\qgis\python, otherwise it wouldn't recognize it. Everytime I update the CSV it'll get the data just fine out of it only if it's the first time I ran it in QGIS. I have noticed that when I change the data in the CSV and run this script again, it updates the dictionary but the script that imports the dictionary keeps using the old one.

Comment: At first glance and without giving too much thought: 'dict' is a keyword - the Dict type. without seeing the rest of your code it looks like you are re-assigning it to an actual dict.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @SeanC. My script uses another name for the dictionary, I used dict only in the example here, I'll change it to something else to make it more clear.

Comment: when you say "using dict_name[1], it actually returns the added_value " do you mean it returns **only** the added_value or a tuple of (original_value, added_value) ? Because if it's the first then original_value is being replaced by added_value and not creating a (original_value, added_value) tuple. A MRE or some actual code would help here.

Comment: also what happens on a third run?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Guy. As sean-c said a bit more of code and a reproducible example will be great. If I have to guess, probably at some point you define a dict as default value for a parameter and it causes de issue https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html

Comment: Thank you, @FranciscoPuga and @SeanC.
It does NOT return only the added value, when I print `dict_name[key]`, I get `{key: (((original values), added_value), added_value)}`. When I run it multiple times I face an error as the data needed to import the layer isn't provided by the dictionary (as the indexing has changed) so I can't tell what happens in that case. 
Added a part of the script in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by making a new dictionary when adding a value instead of adding a value to the existing dictionary.

Instead of `dict_name[key] = dict_name[key], added_value`, I did `new_dict[key] = dict_name[key], added_value` and pulled the specifications for each layer from `new_dict`.